# Saving of data should be intelligent enough to save only member variables that have been populated with proper values?

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

Here is the information about my development environment:

-MongoDB 3.0.0

-MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714

-Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

-.NET Framework 4.0

Let's say that I have the following C# POCO Location class

```
      public class Location

      {

           public Object Id { get; set; }

           public double latitude { get; set; }

           public double longitude { get; set; }

           public String LocDescription { get; set; }

       }
```

The aforementioned class is a C# POCO that will map to a MongoDB collection called Location.

When the application starts up, the following code will get executed from Global.asax.cs

```
        if (false == BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Location)))

        {

            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Location>(cm =>

            {

                cm.AutoMap();

            });



        } //
```

We need the saving to data to be intelligent enough to do the following:

```
   {

       "_id" : ObjectId("567f90bc0a73fc5b0a81f231"),

       "lat" : 309,

       "lng" : 45, 

       "LocDescription" : "passed the bridge, take a left at Rover Street."

  }
```

Or ( In case only a Location Description is provided )

```
   {

       "_id" : ObjectId("5680e1c30a73fc5b0a81f29a"), 

       "LocDescription" : "Going North, take a right at the Eaton Ave & Kennedy Drive.  Take the Overpass to Gaitherburg."

   }
```

Or ( In case only a latitude and longitude are provided  )

```
 {

       "_id" : ObjectId("567f90bc0a73fc5b0a81f231"),

       "lat" : 184,


       "lng" : 22

  }
```

Could someone please tell me how I could modify the  C# POCO Location class, and it's correponding mapping in the Global.asax.cs file so that the aforementioned features of saving can be carried out?  I really want to avoid using Null or Nullable types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`BsonIgnoreIfDefaultAttribute`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.7/html/6c70ebcd-7b01-e2f4-47db-38459f35f1d9.htm) to mark class members whose default values shouldn't be serialized to DB.

In your case, it would be like:

```
public class Location
{
   public Object Id { get; set; }

   [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
   public double latitude { get; set; }

   [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
   public double longitude { get; set; }

   [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
   public String LocDescription { get; set; }
}
```

For string/nullable/object values you can also use [`BsonIgnoreIfNullAttribute`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.7/html/351f430e-5f7f-d97e-02e5-81b4f9c37d3f.htm).